# How to execute a script in XCode build phase as if it was run from the terminal?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, makefile

I created a bash script that runs when building my Objective-C project. The script runs gcc that compiles a a c++ code generator.
When running the script from the terminal, all is well and the executable is created but when its being executed as part of XCode build phase, it fails when linking with the error `error: Unsupported architecture`

the link command is:

```
$(CXX) -o myCodegen myCodegen.cpp -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

My guess is that XCode injects some environment flags or even redefines CXX but I can't find which flags I should override.

Is it possible to run the script as if it was run from the terminal?

Comment: So you are building a project for iOS?  That implies ARM architecture, but I get the impression the compile line you show will build native (x86) architecture code.  Why isn't that source file part of your project proper and therefore these issues are dealt with automatically?

Comment: @trojanfoe Since a code generator builds parts of the project but its not an integral part of it. I could create a new xcodeproj for it but creating a project for one cpp files feels like a huge overhead.

Comment: Add a project target then.

Comment: I think it should be external to the project. There is no way to run a build script in a "clean" environment?